# nginx hotlink protection I added is preventing images from being shown on my website

Tags: nginx, hotlinking

I'm using nginx to serve static files for my website.

I'm trying to protect my static files from hotlinking, so I've done this:

```
location ~*.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$ {
  valid_referers none blocked mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.com ;
   }
```

However, this has stopped my static files from being served from other websites *and* from my website. My website is a white page now. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your HTML loading OK? What do your nginx logs say?

Comment: yes html and css js ok ,ngins say 404 for images files

Comment: What do your log files say?

Comment: 2014/08/12 12:01:21 [error] 3442#0: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/images/bg_content.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 27.28.126.153, server: fanhuaxiu.com, request: "GET /static/images/bg_content.png HTTP/1.1", host: "fanhuaxiu.com", referrer: "http://fanhuaxiu.com/static/css/style.css"

Comment: Does `/usr/share/nginx/html/static/images/bg_content.png` exist?

Comment: 27.28.126.153 - - [12/Aug/2014:12:01:22 +0000] "GET /static/images/bg_footer.png HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "http://fanhuaxiu.com/static/css/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0" "-"

Comment: yes of cause it exit,when i remove this code from nginx ,my website show all the images

Comment: i means the images in the django folder which not /usr/share/nginx/html/static/images/bg_content.png ,it is indeed here /django project/mywebsite/static/bg_content.png