# dose nginx valid_referers really work?

Tags: nginx

i want to protect my website static file hotlink ,so i add config the nginx like this

```
location ~.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
    valid_referers none blocked www.mywebsite.com mywebsite.com ;
    }
```

once i add this code ,all the images file do not shown in my website .till now i do not know why ,you can see my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261177/nginx-hotlink-protection-i-added-is-preventing-images-from-being-shown-on-my-web)

and at last ,i remove the valid_referers this line ,only leave a blank {} there.

```
location ~.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ {

        }
```

nothing changed! ,just like the directive valid_referers do nothing ,my nginx version is the latest version 1.7.4
any one can tell me how to make the valid_referers work.so i can protect my static file in my website.
thanks

Comment: It does work indeed. I use this simple code for image anti-hotlinking.  `location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
  valid_referers server_names
  ~\.google\. ~\.yahoo\. ~\.bing\. ~\.facebook\. ~\.fbcdn\. ~\.ask\. ~\.wp\.;
 if ($invalid_referer) { return 403; }
 }`  ... sorry for formatting not so nice in the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `valid_referers` directive **miss** a `server_names` parameter. Visit [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers) to see more info